# updating sound level freezes my app (i'm using handler.post)

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

First a small introduction. I need to make an app that records sound at a high level of accuracy. Requirements are that i make an app that records at a 10 or more samples per millisecond.

Edit: initialization of the handler.

```
public class MyApp extends AppCompatActivity {
    <Initialize everything>
    Handler handler= new Handler();
}
```

I have a start button that needs to do a few things and at the end it needs to measure my sound level.

```
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {    
        <intitializing sound stuff>

        handler.post(updateSoundLevel);
    }
});
```

This goes to the following loop.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    <Initialize buttons and some variables>
    final Runnable updateSoundLevel = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (SoundRecording==true)
            {
                handler.post(this);
                    <here is measure the time and amplitude>   
            }
        }
    };
};
```

The problem is that i can't push the 'stoprecording' button while this is running. changing this to:`handler.postdelayed(updateSoundLevel, 1)` is not an option cause this slows the whole thing down by 1ms meaning i can't get 10 samples per ms.

If i use `handler.postdelayed(this,1)` i can actually make the program work. And i can stop the recording.

```
buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        //Stop mediarecorder
        try 
        {
            mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(null);
            mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(null);
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(null);
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        { <error message> }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        { <error message> }
        catch (Exception e)
        { <error message> }
    <Code to draw a graph, ...>
    }
});
```

Comment: How is `handler` initialised?

Comment: Edited my original post to answer how my handler is initialized

Comment: I assume you mean that the `stoprecording` handler is not executing, even though you can tap the button. How exactly did you determine this? Please add all code related to the `stoprecording`.

Comment: @RubenDefour By default `Handler` is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it, is this instance the Main/UI Thread. So looks like your Runnable is blocking the UI Thread, causing the app to freeze.

Comment: Is there a way i can break the 'loop' by checking if a button is pressed? 
Or is there a alternative to `Handler`. 
The weird thing is that i can stop recording if i change my `Handler` to `handler.postdelayed(this,1)`. 

I will add my code for the stoprecording now.

Comment: I see no reason your Handler should execute on UI Thread. Have a look a the HandlerThread class. It makes it easy to post Runnable to background thread.

Comment: @veritas1 you're right i can execute this in another Thread but the same problem occurs.